# Email rejected as spam goes through on a reply

Tags: email, spam

Having some problems with mail messages which are rejected as spam when sent directly to a user at a certain company address but if that users sends us a message and we reply, it is accepted.  If I try connecting via smtp on command line from our server, the connection is received.  Any ideas why a direct message is rejected as spam?

Comment: You need to ask the admin of that company, no one here can say what they're running or what policies they have in place.

Answer (score 5):

Quite a few spam filtering systems rank incoming e-mail lower if it references e-mail that was send from the receiving organization. The replying party adds a `In-Reply-To:` header referencing the original e-mail to the message. A quick lookup verifies the reference and mail gets through.

Your original e-mail is probably marked as spam for one or more of the most common reasons:

- Forward/Reverse DNS and HELO/EHLO improperly configured
- SPF record wrong/missing/etc
- IP Reputation (DBSBL, SenderScore, and similar)
- Your sending spam (or something that look a *lot* like spam)